# Reduce Clustered Index seek cost SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running a query and it has records in the hundreds of thousands, it takes more than 20 mins to fetch data. After running the execution plan i noticed that clustered index seek cost can be be the reason. How can I reduce the clustered index seek cost of below mentioned query?

Foreign keys costs around 13% to 23%.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[Test] (@UserTypeID  INT,
                          @UserID      INT,
                          @CityID      INT,
                          @OperatorID  INT,
                          @ParameterID INT)
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @temp TABLE (
        range  DECIMAL(18, 2),
        range2 DECIMAL(18, 2),
        image  VARCHAR(50),
        symbol VARCHAR(20))

      IF( @UserID > 0 )
        BEGIN
            --print 'hii'    
            INSERT INTO @temp
                        (range,
                         range2,
                         image,
                         symbol)
            SELECT tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.range,
                   tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.range2,
                   tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.image,
                   tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.symbol
            FROM   tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls
                   INNER JOIN tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork
                     ON tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.tbl_legend_view_network_id = tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.id
            WHERE  tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.parameter_id = @ParameterID
                   AND tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.user_type_id = @UserTypeID
                   AND tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.is_default = 1
                   AND tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.user_id = @UserID

            UPDATE @temp
            SET    range = range2,
                   range2 = range
            WHERE  symbol = '<'
        END
      ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @temp
                        (range,
                         range2,
                         image,
                         symbol)
            SELECT tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.range,
                   tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.range2,
                   tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.image,
                   tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.symbol
            FROM   tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls
                   INNER JOIN tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork
                     ON tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.tbl_legend_view_network_id = tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.id
            WHERE  tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.parameter_id = @ParameterID
                   AND tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.user_type_id = @UserTypeID
                   AND tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.is_default = 1

            UPDATE @temp
            SET    range = range2,
                   range2 = range
            WHERE  symbol = '<'
        END

      --select * from @temp          
      SELECT '[' + STUFF((SELECT ',{"latitude":"' + a.lat + '","longitude":"' + a.long + '","value":"' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), a.value) + '","image":"' + temp.image + '"}'
                          FROM   (SELECT tbl_Survey_Details.lat,
                                         tbl_Survey_Details.long,
                                         tbl_Survey_Details.value
                                  FROM   tbl_Survey_Details
                                         INNER JOIN tbl_Survey
                                           ON tbl_Survey_Details.tbl_survey_id = tbl_Survey.id
                                         INNER JOIN tbl_Location
                                           ON tbl_Survey.tbl_location_id = tbl_Location.id
                                         INNER JOIN tbl_Area
                                           ON tbl_Location.tbl_area_id = tbl_Area.id
                                         INNER JOIN tbl_City
                                           ON tbl_Area.tbl_city_id = tbl_City.id
                                  WHERE  tbl_Survey_Details.tbl_parameter_id = @ParameterID
                                         AND tbl_Survey.tbl_mobile_operator_id = @OperatorID
                                         AND tbl_Area.tbl_city_id = @CityID) AS a
                                 INNER JOIN @temp temp
                                   ON a.value BETWEEN temp.range AND temp.range2
                          FOR XML Path ('')), 1, 1, '') + ']' AS data
  END
```

[image: Execution plan screenshot]

Revised Query:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[Test] (@UserTypeID  INT,
                          @UserID      INT,
                          @CityID      INT,
                          @OperatorID  INT,
                          @ParameterID INT)
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @temp TABLE (
        range  DECIMAL(18, 2),
        range2 DECIMAL(18, 2),
        image  VARCHAR(50),
        symbol VARCHAR(20))

      IF( @UserID > 0 )
        BEGIN
            --print 'hii'    
            INSERT INTO @temp
                        (range,
                         range2,
                         image,
                         symbol)
            SELECT tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.range,
                   tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.range2,
                   tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.image,
                   tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.symbol
            FROM   tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls
                   INNER JOIN tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork
                     ON tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.tbl_legend_view_network_id = tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.id
            WHERE  tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.parameter_id = @ParameterID
                   AND tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.user_type_id = @UserTypeID
                   AND tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.is_default = 1
                   AND tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.user_id = @UserID

            UPDATE @temp
            SET    range = range2,
                   range2 = range
            WHERE  symbol = '<'
        END
      ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @temp
                        (range,
                         range2,
                         image,
                         symbol)
            SELECT tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.range,
                   tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.range2,
                   tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.image,
                   tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.symbol
            FROM   tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls
                   INNER JOIN tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork
                     ON tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.tbl_legend_view_network_id = tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.id
            WHERE  tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.parameter_id = @ParameterID
                   AND tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.user_type_id = @UserTypeID
                   AND tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.is_default = 1

            UPDATE @temp
            SET    range = range2,
                   range2 = range
            WHERE  symbol = '<'
        END

   SELECT   a.lat, a.long,a.value, temp.image
                          FROM   (SELECT tbl_Survey_Details.lat,
                                         tbl_Survey_Details.long,
                                         tbl_Survey_Details.value
                                  FROM   tbl_Survey_Details
                                         INNER JOIN tbl_Survey
                                           ON tbl_Survey_Details.tbl_survey_id = tbl_Survey.id
                                         INNER JOIN tbl_Location
                                           ON tbl_Survey.tbl_location_id = tbl_Location.id
                                         INNER JOIN tbl_Area
                                           ON tbl_Location.tbl_area_id = tbl_Area.id
                                         INNER JOIN tbl_City
                                           ON tbl_Area.tbl_city_id = tbl_City.id
                                  WHERE  tbl_Survey_Details.tbl_parameter_id = @ParameterID
                                         AND tbl_Survey.tbl_mobile_operator_id = @OperatorID
                                         AND tbl_Area.tbl_city_id = @CityID) AS a
                                 INNER JOIN @temp temp
                                   ON a.value BETWEEN temp.range AND temp.range2

  END
```

Revised Execution Plan:
[image: Revised Execution Plan]

Link to XML Execution plan file : [click here](https://hotfile.com/dl/225503951/44f35b7/sql.sqlplan.html)

Comment: I suspect the actual cost/time is mostly in the XML, which is not normally expanded in the execution plan (because it's a function call).  You're joining on an XML value function output, which is not sargable unless you have XML indexes in place.

Comment: That XML UDX bit at the end of the execution plan is probably the worst thing in the query, but the optimizer can't calculate the cost so it shows it at 0%

Comment: Well you are creating XML and then querying it - can you not just query the tables directly?

Comment: That clustered index scan on the inside of the nested loops looks possibly problematic. How many rows does `tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_DTLS` have? How many executions of the scan are happening? Uploading the XML for the actual execution plan would be best.

Comment: @MartinSmith also the nested loop on the left of the one you mentioned looks problematic. Thick data line from Tbl_Area and thick data line from Tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_DTLS. Maybe a nested loop is not the most appropriate here.

Comment: @Marian - Yes. The thin line out of the compute scalar is the estimated I think so maybe if the estimated was more accurate it wouldn't use nested loops there.

Comment: This plan doesn't seem to correspond to any of the query text in the question though.

Comment: Well guys I had removed the XML part and it create a positive impact, query is taking around 4 mins now. 

Can you guys suggest me how can i reduce this time under 1 or 2 mins?

Comment: First observation: your stats seem stale, look at the data line coming from tbl_Survey_Details (actual no of rows = 250k, estimated = 1). Same for tbl_Location and others. That Nested Loop is bit of a killer there (both operators are big, NL is appropriate when one table is pretty small). The table scan for [@temp] shows it has 750K rows, while the first insert shows 3 rows. Which one is correct? If the first one, then you should replace the [@temp] with a #temp table (with index on the join columns).

Comment: @Marian i remove this [@temp] concept and the part remained is the select query only. and it still takes 4-5 mins in fetching around 300k records.

Comment: Can you update the statistics of the tables involved (to remove the discrepancy between actual and estimated rows)?

Comment: @Marian i ran a query stating "select top(300000) lat, long from tbl_Survey_Details" and it is also approx consuming same time with a difference of 15 - 20 secs.

Answer (score 7):

Since it takes about the same amount of time to fetch 300,000 rows using a very simple query, I'd suggest you stop looking at query tuning temporarily and decide whether the specific scenario you're currently testing is realistic.

- You are running Management Studio on your local workstation, connected to a SQL Server instance on a godaddy server, somewhere. Therefore on top of cost of the query within SQL Server, you are also constrained by:

  - godaddy's bandwidth (shared with other people connecting to those servers)
  - your bandwidth (potentially shared with other people in your house and your neighborhood)
  - the time it takes Management Studio to gather the results and, more importantly, render them
- You are retrieving 300,000 rows in your result. Usually this is not something you do - what user is going to consume 300,000 rows? Consider aggregating or only returning a subset on each pull (Google doesn't return 300,000 results in a single page, they show you 10 results at a time), and thinking about what purpose this query actually serves.

Since it is unlikely that this is how your database will be expected to produce results in reality, I suggest you change your testing methodology somewhat. Either have Management Studio installed on some server *within* godaddy's infrastructure, taking bandwidth and general Internet volatility out of the equation, or test your query logic using your local copy of Management Studio, but don't use that for **timing** the results. Rather, use an app within godaddy's infrastructure to test the timing (after all, this is how your application will eventually work, right?).

If the query is also slow when you've taken bandwidth/Internet out of the picture, then you can start to consider whether the I/O you're getting from godaddy's server is sufficient (or whether you really need to pull 300,000 rows at any one time anyway, so maybe the point is moot).

Answer (score 2):

These steps should help:

1. Add `OPTION RECOMPILE` to both queries with parameters. It will recompile execution plan for actual parameters' values.
2. You have index on `tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork (parameter_id, user_type_id, is_default,user_id)` with user_id being the last column. Don't you?
3. Create a summary table or materialized view to substitute 3 sequential joins from the 2nd query.
4. Change update statement for a case statement in the query.
5. Use CTE instead of @Temp, as you do not need to update anything
6. Get rid of `IF` by using `user_id=@UserID OR @UserID is null)
7. When you do multiple JOINs you need to filtering as soon as possible. Thus you should do `Select * from tbl_City JOIN ... Where City_id = @CityID`. So you first select 1 city and then join, rather than selecting nay rows, joining to all cities and then filtering.
8. You do not need to JOIN tbl_City in the last query, because you are not using contents on this table anywhere (you use: `tbl_Area.tbl_city_id = @CityID`).
   Here is what I get:

   ```
   CREATE PROC [dbo].[Test] (@UserTypeID  INT,
                         @UserID      INT,
                         @CityID      INT,
                         @OperatorID  INT,
                         @ParameterID INT)
   AS BEGIN

   with cte1 as (
           SELECT 

               case  tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.symbol
               when '<' then tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.range2
               else tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.range
           end 
           as range,

           case  tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.symbol
               when '<' then tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.range
               else tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.range2
           end 
           as range2,
          tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.image
           FROM   tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls
                  INNER JOIN tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork
                    ON tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.tbl_legend_view_network_id = tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.id
           WHERE  tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.parameter_id = @ParameterID
                  AND tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.user_type_id = @UserTypeID
                  AND tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.is_default = 1
                  AND (tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.user_id = @UserID OR @UserID is NULL)


   ),

   cte2 as (

       SELECT  
           tbl_Survey_Details.lat,
                       tbl_Survey_Details.long,
                       tbl_Survey_Details.value

       FROM    tbl_City

       INNER JOIN tbl_Area
           ON tbl_Area_tbl_city_id = tbl_City.id AND tbl_city_id = @CityID

       INNER JOIN tbl_Location
           ON tbl_Location.tbl_area_id = tbl_Area.id

       INNER JOIN tbl_Survey
           ON tbl_Survey.tbl_location_id = tbl_Location.id

       INNER JOIN tbl_Survey_Details
           ON tbl_Survey_Details.tbl_survey_id = tbl_Survey.id

       WHERE   tbl_Survey_Details.tbl_parameter_id = @ParameterID
                       AND 
           tbl_Survey.tbl_mobile_operator_id = @OperatorID
   )


   SELECT  a.lat, a.long,a.value, cte1.image
               FROM cte2

               INNER JOIN cte1
                      ON cte2.value BETWEEN cte1.range AND cte1.range2
   OPTION (RECOMPILE)
   END
   ```

P.S. Marian, thank you for your help with formatting!

Comment: @DeepakD you're fetching 300K rows from a godaddy server. Are you sure the problem is the query, and not the fetching of 300K rows? How long does it take `SELECT TOP 300000 * FROM dbo.Some_Big_Enough_Table;`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand i created simple query according to you. And it is taking approx same time (with a difference of 15-20 secs) as my original query. i don't know what to do now. :(

Comment: I'm afraid there is nothing you can do further without SQL Profiler. Use it to find out bottlenecks on your server (I/O, CPU, Memory). To me it seems to be a constrain on data reading (I/O ~ HDD reading speed) performance of your hardware. There a limit how fast a query will run on any given hardware.

Comment: Another thing you can try, actually, is try to get this data set in parts using several connections from your applicaion (where the data goes to). If you have several disks, then store parts of your table on different disks to increase reading speed. You can look at partitioning, but it looks like overshoot to me. If you are bound by HDD reading speed, then partitioning and straming  would not help much.